# Use of em dash instead of period

Tags: meaning-in-context, punctuation

'Ron, be quiet!' Hermione whispered urgently.

'Fudge'll be out here in a minute -'

1)'**He - won't - stay - put **-** '**

Scabbers was plainly terrified. He was writhing with all his might, trying to break free of Ron's grip.

2)**'What's the *matter* with him?'**

But Harry had just seen -

a) If you notice in question 1, Ron has completed his sentence and no one intervene either.
Then why

'He - won't - stay - put - '

instead of

'He - won't - stay - put. '

Why not full stop but em dash at last?

b) Who is saying the (2) line and **how do you determine that**?

Comment: _You should always give the source of a passage you are asking about_, though we can easily guess that this is one of the Harry Potter books. I don't know why it is punctuated as it is (I would have used suspension points ... rather than dashes), but presumably Ron is  portrayed as saying disjointed words while struggling with the rat rather than a proper sentence.

Comment: Yes it's Harry Potter and you should always consider reading question first.

Comment: You still haven't said _which_ book! Of course I read the question. Without having read the whole passage I can't tell who asked "What's the matter with him?" - presumably Ron, but possibly Hermione.

Comment: It's Prisoner of Azkaban. And my question persons to the sentences written in bold.

Comment: P.S After that dialogue, it mentions "Harry had just seen" does it imply he spoke the former dialogue?

Comment: Yes, I know your question pertains to the sentences in bold. I referred to the first one in my original comment. My guess is that Ron asked the question **but** Harry ignored him because he had just seen... [something else].

Comment: Read from a) if you notice in question ... It's on me. I couldn't make myself clear. That was my first question.

Comment: And my first comment was in answer to it. I don't know why JKR used that punctuation.

Comment: Is there anyone who knows the answer. I'd be grateful for that.

Comment: I suspect only Ms Rowling herself could tell you that!

Comment: Kate, how do you all read books, don't you get confused by all this, I really want to know.

Comment: A minor quibble about the author's choice of punctuation wouldn't be enough to spoil my enjoyment of a book.